# How to add Spatial Reference ID 28992 to MSSQL server?

Tags: sql-server, xml, spatial, geometry, srid

I want to use Spatial Reference ID 28992, as found on [EPSG](https://epsg.io/28992), in MS SQL Server. How can I add this to MS SQL Server?

My end goal is to get [this](https://zakelijk.kadaster.nl/documents/20838/87954/Proefbestand+heel+Nederland/0a19ce51-4e82-db0e-9377-80f7d096eff4) dataset into MS SQL Server, with the Geography Markup Language (GML) elements are stored in MS SQL Server's geography data type. After this, I want to make a connection to the MS SQL Server from [QGIS](https://qgis.org/en/site/), so I can do some nice data analyses.

My idea was to parse the GML elements (that are contained in an XML) using the [GEOMFROMGML parser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geography/geomfromgml-geography-data-type?view=sql-server-ver15) from MS SQL Server. I tried:

```
SELECT geography::GeomFromGml (
'<Polygon xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
<exterior>
<LinearRing>
<posList>78988.952 384548.144 78992.462 384549.74 78998.712 384555.12</posList>
</LinearRing>
</exterior>
</Polygon>'
, 28992 )
```

However, the above code gives the following error:
"The spatial reference identifier (SRID) is not valid. The specified SRID must match one of the supported SRIDs displayed in the sys.spatial_reference_systems catalog view."

So, I tried to add the SRID to sys.spatial_reference_systems catalog view, using:

```
INSERT INTO [DataAnalyse].[sys].[spatial_reference_systems] ([spatial_reference_id]
      ,[authority_name]
      ,[authorized_spatial_reference_id]
      ,[well_known_text]
      ,[unit_of_measure]
      ,[unit_conversion_factor])
VALUES(
    28992,
    'EPSG',
    28992,
    'GEOGCS["Amersfoort", DATUM["Amersfoort", SPHEROID["Bessel 1841", 6377397.155,299.1528128]], PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0], UNIT["Degree", 0.0174532925199433]]',
    'metre',
    1
)
```

This gave another error: "Msg 259, Level 16, State 1, Line 13
Ad hoc updates to system catalogs are not allowed."

So, I looked how I could update a system catalog. It was explained on [DBA](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/192901/how-do-you-directly-modify-the-system-catalogs-in-sql-server-2017) how to do this. But it was stated there that there is a severe risk of breaking your MS SQL Server installation, and that warranty would cease. So, it seems that updating the system catalog directly is not really an option.

I first asked this question on [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-spatial-reference-systems-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) but I was told to ask my question here.

Moreover, people seem to have asked similar questions:

- [How to add new spatial reference system (on SQLservercentral)](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/how-to-add-new-spatial-reference-system) asked in 2011, no response.
- [Insert new spatial reference system SRID into SQL Server (on stackoverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58766917/insert-new-spatial-reference-system-srid-into-sql-server) asked 2019, no response.

If you have an answer to my question, or have a different idea to get me to my end goal (stated above) please let me know.

Comment: sys.spatial_reference_systems is just a list of SRIDs supported by SQL Server

Answer (score 1):

> I want to use Spatial Reference ID 28992, as found on EPSG, in MS SQL Server. How can I add this to MS SQL Server?

As you've mentioned, there are ways to modify system catalogs manually but in general this is not supported or recommended. As such, I consider this a non-option.

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/spatial/create-construct-and-query-geography-instances?view=sql-server-ver15#supportedsrid) specifies:

> SQL Server supports SRIDs based on the EPSG standards. **A SQL Server-supported SRID for geography instances must be used** when performing calculations or using methods with geography spatial data. The **SRID must match one of the SRIDs displayed in the sys.spatial_reference_systems** catalog view.

*Emphasis mine*.

So it seems to be clear that SQL Server does not support this particular SRID (as of SQL Server 2019 - [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0a09601194f43b4a33ac826250d6999a)).

---

That being said, you should

1. [Create a feedback item](https://aka.ms/sqlfeedback) for the MSSQL team about adding this functionality.
2. Look into [PostGIS](http://postgis.net/) which is widely considered the best option for handling GIS data in a relational database (and free, to boot).